# How to offset a range in a for loop

Tags: vba, for-loop

I want to offset my rng2 for each cell in rng1

Right now in my Rng2, Q is default set to zero

Each time i loop through a new cell(my first for loop) I want Q to increase by 1 because for each cell in Rng, I want to match on a new row.

Where Do I put Q = Q + 1 in my code
The rest of my code works fine, I just want to offset my rng2 by one row, each time i loop through a new cell in rng1. Any help would be appreciated

```
    Sub StructurePivot2()
    Dim X As Variant, Var As Double, D As Integer, P As Integer, Q As Integer, Z As Integer, ws As Worksheet, rng3 As Range, category As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Variant, i As Integer, rng2 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A173")
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:AI2").Offset(Q)
    P = 0
        For Each cell In rng

                        For i = 1 To 5

                          Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rng2, 0)
                          Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Offset(P, 13) = Z
                          P = P + 1

                     Next i

Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop:

```
Next i
set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1, 0) 'Advance to next row
Next cell
```